# Vscode not opening on arm64 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, arm64

I have successfully installed vscode on my arm64 ubuntu 20.04 machine by downloading the arm64 .deb file from VS's website (https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and used `sudo apt install` on the .deb file to install. The installation was completed without error, and vscode was now shown as an application in the system. However, when I tried clicking on the app, absolutely nothing happened.

I also tried launching it in terminal with `code`, again nothing happened with no output, and the process never terminated until key interrupted.

I then tried `code --verbose`, and again the nothingness with **no** output.

What might be causing this, and any potential solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try running with:

```bash
code --no-sandbox
```